# What is the Regex expression to get resultset element from xml string?

Tags: regex, xml

Would like help to trim the result set elements from my overall XML. The schema of the XML sting is not needed. Would only like the resultSet elements of the xmls.

Below is my xml string:

```
<NewDataSet>
           <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
              <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="resultSet" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                 <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                       <xs:element name="resultSet">
                          <xs:complexType>
                             <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="WAMUserName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="AppPoolState" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="Validation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                             </xs:sequence>
                          </xs:complexType>
                       </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
           </xs:schema>
           <resultSet>
              <Name />
              <WAMUserName />
              <AppPoolState />
              <Validation />
           </resultSet>
           <resultSet>
              <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KTSAAppPool</Name>
              <WAMUserName>ST\nzsktsa</WAMUserName>
              <AppPoolState>Disabling</AppPoolState>
              <Validation>Critical</Validation>
           </resultSet>
           <resultSet>
              <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KCPSAAppPool</Name>
              <WAMUserName>st\nzsOFSA</WAMUserName>
              <AppPoolState>Running</AppPoolState>
              <Validation>Critical</Validation>
           </resultSet>
</NewDataSet>
```

Would like the below output as part of regex expression.

```
<resultSet>
      <Name />
      <WAMUserName />
      <AppPoolState />
      <Validation />
   </resultSet>
   <resultSet>
      <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KTSAAppPool</Name>
      <WAMUserName>ST\nzsktsa</WAMUserName>
      <AppPoolState>Disabling</AppPoolState>
      <Validation>Critical</Validation>
   </resultSet>
   <resultSet>
      <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KCPSAAppPool</Name>
      <WAMUserName>st\nzsOFSA</WAMUserName>
      <AppPoolState>Running</AppPoolState>
      <Validation>Critical</Validation>
</resultSet>
```

Comment: What language or tool are you using? You're probably better off with an XML parser.

Comment: Java based chatOps platform. Problem is, we only have regex but not XML parser :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess. But however, you shouldn't use RegEx'es to process XML files. Use an XSLT processor like `xsltproc` (Linux)  or `Saxon` (Java) or `Xerces` (Java).

Using an XSLT-1.0 processor, you can extract the `resultSet` elements easily with the following template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="resultSet" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply it to your XML file and the result will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultSet>
    <Name/>
    <WAMUserName/>
    <AppPoolState/>
    <Validation/>
</resultSet>
<resultSet>
    <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KTSAAppPool</Name>
    <WAMUserName>ST\nzsktsa</WAMUserName>
    <AppPoolState>Disabling</AppPoolState>
    <Validation>Critical</Validation>
</resultSet>
<resultSet>
    <Name>W3SVC/APPPOOLS/KCPSAAppPool</Name>
    <WAMUserName>st\nzsOFSA</WAMUserName>
    <AppPoolState>Running</AppPoolState>
    <Validation>Critical</Validation>
</resultSet>
```

The command depends on your XSLT processor.